# парсинг 1 track.ru

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Для начала хочу получить код html странички по треку, но при выполнении всех махинаций...текст с датами и местами отслеживания посылки на странице отсутствует.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import re



chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver =   
webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Yres\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\
chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get('https://1track.ru/tracking/RU341961010HK')

time.sleep(30)
#driver.headless =True
#element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-dialog")))
#driver.find_element_by_class_name ("btn ").click()


driver.find_element_by_class_name ("close").click()
driver.get('https://1track.ru/tracking/RU341961010HK')
source = driver.page_source
#driver.quit() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print(soup)


#s = requests.Session()
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить user-agent информацию.

Comment: как? а что она даёт?

Comment: ну она дает сайту больше информации о клиенте.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python

Comment: спасибо,сейчас попробую

Comment: Я почитал, но не понял где мне изменить. У меня driver.get, а там с requests.get реализовано или с session.get

Comment: Ещё могу так же предложить повторить get или post запрос который формирует браузер при запросе трек кода.

Comment: Либо попробовать поработать с их API.
Например https://1track.ru/b2b/widget или https://1track.ru/b2b